# Kotlin not accepting String as Any?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun foo(map: MutableMap<String, Any>) {
    println(map)
}

foo(mutableMapOf<String, String>("bar" to "baz"))
```

This results in the following error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableMap<String, String> but MutableMap<String, Any> was expected
```

With `Any` being the root class of all classes in Kotlin, shouldn't this be allowed?

A possible solution is to declare the input as `mutableMapOf<String, Any>("bar" to "baz")` but that feels unneccesary.

Answer (score 4):

> With Any being the root class of all classes in Kotlin, shouldn't this be allowed?

Not when it comes to generics.

The function takes a MutableMap<String, Any>, which means the function could put *anything* in that map. You pass it a MutableMap<String, String>. So what happens if the function tries to put in some other object?

```
map["foo"] = SomeObject() // map is type <String, String>, this goes boom
```

To make this work you need to indicate the [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) of the map. In this case, your function only *reads* from the map, so you can indicate this with a [use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) by marking the map with the `out` keyword:

```
fun foo(map: MutableMap<String, out Any>) {
    println(map)
}
```

Now the compiler knows (and will enforce) that you will only *read* from the map, so it will accept any class that extends from Any.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of people suggesting use-site variance (i.e. `MutableMap<String, out Any>`) which makes very little sense to me. This will basically just turn the parameters of mutating methods like `put` into `never`, which obfuscates your intent (wanting to accept a read-only map), and makes your function incompatible objects that only implement the canonical read-only `Map<K, V>` interface.

Much simpler would be just to modify the function signature:

```
fun foo(map: Map<String, Any>) {
    println(map)
}

foo(mutableMapOf<String, String>("bar" to "baz")) // tada
```

If you're confused as to why this is necessary, consider this scenario:

```
fun foo(map: MutableMap<String, Any>) {
    map["hello"] = 6
}

val stringMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>("bar" to "baz")
foo(stringMap) // bad

val notAString: String = stringMap["hello"] // oh no!
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) `out` on the Any type in foo function.

```kotlin
fun foo(map: MutableMap<String, out Any> { } 

foo(mutableMapOf<String, String>())
```